# All possible combination of an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, combinations

I am trying to find all possible combination of an array. I could not find a similar question so I ask here.

Suppose that I have arrays A and N , integer T as input and I need to find all possible combination of array S, that satisfies following inequality.

---

Input : A(a1,a2,...,ak) ,   N(n1,n2,...,nk)   , int T

Output : S(s1,s2,....sk)

subject to :

sum ( si*ai ) <= T

and

for each i: si<= ni

---

Any idea? how do you implement it ? I will use c++ for its implementation.

Comment: You say you are looking for subarrays `S` of `N`.  However, two things stand out to me.  If `N=(n1,n2,...,nk)` and `S=(s1,s2,...,sk)` then `|N|=|S|` and the only valid subarray is if `N=S`.  You also state that `for each i: si <= ni` implying that it is possible that some `si` elements may not be in `N`.  This is contrary to my understanding of a subarray.  Can you clarify these points?  It's not clear, at best, what it is you are looking for here.

Comment: @huck_cussler you`re right , it is not subarray ,  I just didn`t know that how to name it. for example : N=[0,2,3,0,1] , one possible is S=[0,1,2,0,0] or S=[0,2,0,0,1], I corrected the question.

Comment: Are `A`, `S`, `N` arrays of integers, natural numbers, real numbers, ...?

Comment: @huck_cussler N and S are arrays of integers.  A can be real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be cases where there are no solutions, infinitely many solutions, and a finite number of solutions.

First, define `SUM(X,Y) = x_1*y_1 + x_2*y_2 + ... + x_k*y_k`.

if `SUM(A,N) <= T` then `N` is a solution.

Next, let `Ni = (n_1, n_2, ..., [n_i]-1, ..., n_k)`.  If `SUM(A,Ni) < SUM(A,N)` for any `i` from `1` to `k` then there are infinitely many solutions.  We can't enumerate them and we're done.

Otherwise, if `N` is not a solution, then there are no solutions and we're done.

Finally, if neither of the two above cases hold, then there are finitely many solutions.  To enumerate them, iterate from `i=1` to `k` again and, holding all other `n` constant, keep decrementing `n_i` by one to get `Ni'` and checking if `SUM(A,Ni') <= T`.  Keep track of these ranges for each `n` as these will be the maximum ranges by which each `n` can vary independently of the others and still (possibly) give a solution.

Lastly, iterate through the Cartesian product of all the `n`-ranges determined and check to see if each combination is a solution.

There may still be some corner cases I am missing but this is mostly a correct solution I believe.